# Syntax Error MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm stuck on this SQL, it is saying that I am missing an operator and highlighting `"Available"`. What I am trying to do is create this Update query in VBA, I need the field `[TS]` to update but only if the `[Status]` is "Available". Here's the full code below:

`UPDATE attendance SET TS = " & iif [Status] = "Available" Then DMax("[TS]", "attendance") + 1 & " WHERE [userID]= " & rs!userID`

I'm thinking I may not have this statement in the correct order.

Comment: If you have an iif condition, don't you also need an else condition?

Comment: I thought that if you have an IF/THEN statement the else is optional (Else).

Comment: The quote after SET TS = " has never been closed ?

Comment: It's closed after the `+ 1` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"IIF" is a function that expects three parameters (wrapped in parenthesis), and returns either the true-result or the false-result depending on the value of the condition, like this: iif(condition, true-result, false-result).

But, even if you fixed that syntax error in your query, I don't think your query would do what you are hoping for.  Maybe something like this would work better:

```
"UPDATE attendance SET [TS]= [TS]+1 WHERE [userID]=" & rs!userID & " AND [Status]=""Available"""
```